# How to remove view at certain position in adapter in android xamrian

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

this is my code in Adapter
Here 2 different views that come on different condtions when id == 19 than i am going to show newOrderedDesc,newQty in below where desc,OrderedQty is..

desc,OrderedQty is going to show where id != 19
below if ,else conditons working as expected but problem is it genrating empty view.. that i dont want to genrate

I mean the view of desc,orderedqty is generating new empty view that I don't want

```
 view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Myadapter, parent, false);

  var desc = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.OrderedDesc);
  var OrderedQty = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.OrderedQty);

  var x = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.x);
  var newOrderedDesc = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.newOrderedDesc);
  var newQty = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.newitemQty);

  if (MyConvert.ToInt32(Getitem[position].id) == 19)
  {
      x.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
      newOrderedDesc.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
      newQty.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
  }
  view.Tag = new Myadapter()
  {
      desc = OrderedDesc,
      OrderedQty = OrderedQty,
      newOrderedDesc = newOrderedDesc,
      newQty = newitemQty
  };
  
 if (MyConvert.ToInt32(Getitem[position].id) == 19)
 {
     holder.newOrderedDesc.Text = Getitem[position].Description.Trim();
     holder.newQty.Text = MyConvert.ToString(Getitem[position].Quantity).Trim();
 }
 else
 {
     holder.desc.Text = Getitem[position].Description.Trim();
     holder.OrderedQty.Text = MyConvert.ToString(Getitem[position].Quantity).Trim();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide desc & OrderedQty View where You showing newOrderedDesc & newQty

Here is the modified version of your code

```
 if (MyConvert.ToInt32(Getitem[position].id) == 19)
  {
      x.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
      newOrderedDesc.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
      newQty.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

      desc.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
      OrderedQty.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
  }
```

last 2 lines will solve your new empty view genration problem